# Is it possible to load multiple resources in routing.yml?

Tags: php, symfony

is it possible to add multiple resources into routing.yml?

I've tried this, but only the first one is loaded:

```
#routing.yml
myApp:
    resource: '../../src/Module1/Controller'
    resource: '../../src/Module2/Controller'
    type:     annotation
    prefix:   /myApp
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, but each resource should be a seperate entry:

```
foo:
    resource: '../../src/Module1/Controller'
    type: annotation
    prefix: /myApp

bar:
    resource: '../../src/Module2/Controller'
    type: annotation
    prefix: /myApp
```